# Any list/database of sets and components online?

Tags: lego-group

I'm searching for a list/site that show every public sets/and or individual components, with possibly their image representation attached.

I'm aware i could directly look on the main website, but i learned that a lots of old sets (pre 2000 to 2010 and later) are what you would call *rare* and can only be found by particular vendors, or sold as used on Ebay...

I'm mostly interested in their names and dimension/any details relevant to them, including rare/non-existing, and recent ones.

Any advice/input is welcome.

Comment: That does yeah :) Though Syberion already answered too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Brickset](http://brickset.com/) has a nearly complete database of LEGO sets with inventories,

There is also [Bricklink](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/main.page), which is a marketplace , but also can be uses an excellent database